# is there $index iterator for wjFlexChart binding (wijmo 5 flex chart)?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, wijmo, flex-charts

as I understand `data-bind="wjFlexChart: { itemsSource: data, bindingX: 'week' }` iterates through all items in array `data` (like foreach knockout binding).

My questions are:
1) how can I access current element Id ($index doesn't work)?
2) are $data, $parent the same as $data, $parent for knockout foreach binding?

Comment: Try this: 1) open your browsers developer tools 2) in the inspector, highlight / click on a HTML child element inside the container with the `data-bind="wjFlexChart` 3) in the console, enter `ko.contextFor($0)`. This will show you all the properties of the binding context. [Example screenshot on how to use `ko.contextFor`](http://i.imgur.com/qXWF2ot.jpg).

Comment: The chart's binding/rendering happens outside of Knockout if that helps.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @rrjohnson85, here is the post about what im trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321738/wijmo-5-flex-chart-doesnt-work-with-knockout-foreach-binding?noredirect=1#comment48773413_30321738